# Usage of higher impedance headphones with motherboard that can handle only half

Tags: audio, motherboard, headphones

How bad would it be if I used headphones with an impedance of 63 ohms with a motherboard that can fully manage only 32 ohms? (I asked the manufacturer how much my MB can handle)

If I understand correctly, the maximum volume would be reduced. But by how much? 50% in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Usage of higher impedance headphones with motherboard that can handle only half

There's no issue using higher impedance headphones.
After all, having no headphones is an infinite impedance, and nothing burns up.
The problem occurs when you try to use a lower impedance than what the motherboard's amplifier can handle.

> How bad would it be if I used headphones with an impedance of 63 ohms with a motherboard that can fully manage only 32 ohms?

The difference may not even be noticeable.

> If I understand correctly, the maximum volume would be reduced. But by how much? 50% in this case?

Yes, the maximum volume would be reduced. 
Be careful to not confuse power with sound level.

The power delivered could be reduced by about half, i.e. -3dB.
Reduction in sound level should be much less, since 10dB of power corresponds to a doubling or halving of sound level.

Also note that the efficiency or sensitivity (i.e. sound level measured in dB SPL per milliwatt of power) of the headphones affects whether you notice the reduction in power.
If the headphones are very efficient, then driving it with maximum power could be too loud to be comfortable.